# ErrorType protocol in weather app

Tags: error-handling, swift2, swift-protocols

I am very new to Swift and trying to create weather app. I have protocol `func weatherManagerFailedToLoadCityWithError(error: ErrorType)`. In weatherManager.swift have some delegate

```
} else if status == 404 {
                // City not found
                if self.delegate != nil {
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                        self.delegate?.weatherManagerFailerToLoadCityWithError(.InvalidResponse)
                    })
                }

            } else {
                // Some other here?
                if self.delegate != nil {
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                        self.delegate?.weatherManagerFailerToLoadCityWithError(.MissingData)
                    })
                }
            }
```

What should i do i weatherController.swift in this code block

```
func weatherManagerFailedToLoadCityWithError(error: ErrorType) {

}
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
private struct ErrorInformation {
    static let Domain = "us.firmaName"
    static let ServerNotFoundDomain = "\(ErrorInformation.Domain).notFound"
}

private extension NSError {
    static func serverNotFound() -> NSError {
       let userInfo = [
           NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: NSLocalizedString("Server Not Found", comment: ""),
           NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey: NSLocalizedString("The Server you are asking for is not available.", comment: ""),
           NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestionErrorKey: NSLocalizedString("Please proof your URL bla-bla-bla.", comment: "")
       ]

    return NSError(domain: ErrorInformation.ServerNotFoundDomain, code: 404, userInfo: userInfo)
}
```

And then call your function:

```
weatherManagerFailedToLoadCityWithError(error: NSError.serverNotFound())
```

If you want you can handle the Error in your function:

```
func weatherManagerFailedToLoadCityWithError(error: ErrorType) {
   print("Error description: \(error.userInfo. NSLocalizedDescriptionKey)")
}
```

If you want more explanation, just post more of your code.